# Asp.net Core Identity Tokens Generation

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm implementing an application composed by an identity provider (Identity Server 4 + ASP Identity Core) and two other applications (ASP.NET Core 2) that are using the first one to authenticate.

So far so good, however I need to create user accounts directly in the client applications and I would like to use the ASP.NET Core Identity functionalities to generate tokens for email/account verification and i'm wondering what is the better way to approach it.

Because I'm trying to avoid to register a bunch of Identity services (managers, stores, ...) in my client applications the first things that came to my mind to implement this were:

- Custom API endpoint (IDSRV4) that can be invoked from the client apps to generate the tokens (or generate the tokens and send the email) using the UserManager.
- Shared custom TokenProviders to generate the tokens that can be used in both IDSRV and clients.

Am I missing the trick here, and is there any simpler way to solve this problem?